# Web Server on Android phone

Tags: android, restlet

I'm trying to set up a web server using the Restlet framework on my Android phone. My idea is to build a game where one phone creates some markers on a map which then can be transferred directly to other phones using rest. At first (and for simplicity) I want to transfer a `List` of `Objects`.

Running a server on my computer seems to work fine, but when I transfer the code to my Android application, it won't start the server. Here is the code:

```
Component serverComponent = new Component();
serverComponent.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 80);  
final Router router = new Router(serverComponent.getContext().createChildContext());  
router.attach("/gamedata", GameDataResourceServer.class);  
serverComponent.getDefaultHost().attach(router);  
serverComponent.start();
```

When the line `serverComponent.start();` is executed, this Exception is thrown:
`java.net.BindException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)`, although the internet permission is in the manifest file. Searching for some tutorials didn't help either. The result are either client applications or very complicated scenarios.
Could someone give an example for a simple application?

Comment: So you want to implement a server available in private WiFi networks only - or do you want to start a server open to the public internet?

Comment: Private WiFi only should do the job, but it would be better if it was accessible from public, if, for example, there is no WiFi to transfer the data to other phones. The server needs to run only for a short period of time to allow all players to download the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Unix-type environments you typically need root access to bind to a TCP port below 1024.  You're trying to bind to port 80, and unless you run this code as root the OS will prevent the request.

Comment: So that means I need to choose a port above 1024? Then how can I make sure this port is not blocked by the firewall if run on WiFi?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to use a higher port.  No guarantees that it won't be blocked by the router, but that's really only a concern if you want to allow connections from outside the router.  If that's the case, you'll have to let the user know what port is being used so they can manage.

Comment: @Alex P.: This is how servers work, for security reasons it may become challenging to run a server on an android - especially if you're in a uncontrolled (unknown) environment.

Comment: And are there any ports I need to worry about if running the server over 3G?

Comment: There's a list of "official" registered services and ports [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml) but chances are you won't come across most of them being in-use on Android.

Comment: Thank you all! Now my server is running (over 3G), but there is a new problem:  If I try to connect to it from my PC, the connection times out. The code for the client:  `String IP = "[my_ip_here]:8080";  ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://" + IP + "/gamedata");  IGameDataResource resource = cr.wrap(IGameDataResource.class);  GameData data = resource.retrieveGameData();`  Any ideas whats wrong? Maybe my carrier blocks webservers over 3G?

Comment: @Alex P.: This is what I tried to say. If you want to implement a server on an android phone, you need a publicly available IP address which is not necessarily the case, depends on carrier. Btw, as I'm an android user I personalliy hope you will not find a solution for this as I do not want 'you' to start servers on my phone :-)

Comment: Its entirely possible (and most likely) that your carrier would block incoming connections over 3G to your phone.  If you need to open this up on a public network, you might want to reconsider hosting whatever server component you have on a traditional web server.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I will need to use a differen architecture and put a Computer in between the "host" phone and clients. Thank you for all your help!